LFSR, starting with a known sequence
Its known that cipher is made with LFRS. Cipher text is 868 bits long, and its known that the plaintext starts with "Dear Student", therefore we can get the keystream of first 84 bits. However, we do not know anything about the length of LFRS. I only know that if known portion of a plaintext has a length of 2m and the length of LFRS is m, we can solve m linear equations to get the the connection polynomial. In this example it's not given, so what is the right approach here to find the plaintext? Can anything be done with the acquired 84 bits, its linear complexity is 17 but does it really say anything about the whole keystream?

It says that the linear complexity of the whole key stream is very likely to be 17 (equivalently generated by a 17 long LFSR).

The standard method to solve this is the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm (in the binary field $\mathbb F_2$). Given a sequence of $\ell$ bits $b_i$ believed to be output by a LFSR, it gives the shortest non-inverted LFSR and initial state generating the sequence. The length $m$ of that minimal LFSR is the linear complexity.
When the LFSR is in Fibonnaci form as customary in BM, the initial state is the first $m$ bits $b_j$ for $j\in[0,m)$, and the output is the $m$ bits $x_j$ such that $b_i=b_{i−1}x_1+b_{i−2}x_2+\cdots+b_{i−m}x_m$ for $i\in[m,\ell)$.
For all inputs of BM it holds $\ell\ge2m$. The number of tail bits in the sequence that are successfully predicted by this BM-produced LFSR is $\ell-2m$. Here that's $84-2\times17=50$ bits, which is large enough that we can be confident that the rest of the sequence is correctly predicted and the whole message decipherable.
We do not need to use the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm if for some reason we are told $m=17$: In that case we can solve the $17$ equations resulting from the recurrence $b_i=b_{i−1}x_1+b_{i−2}x_2+\cdots+b_{i−m}x_m$ for $i\in[17,33]$, finding the $17$ unknowns $x_k$ with $k\in[1,17]$. We'll get a single solution and $x_{17}=1$, and this same equation will correctly predicts $b_i$ for $i\in[34,83]$; otherwise $m=17$ was wrong, or the LFSR is inverted.

i didn't get the l - 2m part can you explain it in more detail? Also, meaning decipherable can we say that m = 17 and solve it for 17 linear equations, or is there another way to solve it?

@Metin, look up the berlekamp massey algorithm, make an effort. it gives the shortest LFSR generating the sequence. it solves the problem, the question "is there another way to solve it" is misplaced.

As the comment from from Daniel S says, it is quite possible that the LFSR is indeed only 17 bits long. If you are using the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm to synthesize the LFSR, it will produce the LFSR and then continue to check whether the additional known bits of the keystream are produced by the synthesized LFSR. (From your comment of fgrieu's answer, you apparently are not; for some details on how this works, see the first part of this answer of mine. The statement "Can anything be done with the acquired 84 bits, its linear complexity is 17...." suggests that the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm indeed has been used, and the synthesized LFSR has produced the next 84-7 produced. The proof of the pudding is in the eating; use the synthesized LFSR to generate more bits of the hypothesized keystream and  check whether the decryption of the cipher text continues to provide reasonable plaintext. If it does, you are good to go.  If not, run the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm past the 84 bits and see if the algorithm updates the LFSR (the updated LFSR will have length of around 90 or so.)
